# Integral of a function multiplied by a gaussian without using fourier transform.

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I did some calculations and I ended up with an integral

$$
I(t;\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t') e^{-\frac{(t-t')^2}{4\epsilon^2}} dt'
$$

where $f$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\epsilon > 0$

I want to prove that as $\epsilon \to 0^+$ the integral converges to a multiple of $f(t)$ for fixed $t$. I've tried to use the Cauchy Schwartz inequality, but I ended up with nothing, except an upper bound indipendent from $\epsilon$.

Can you help me? I don't want to use the Fourier transform at this stage.

Comment: I guess, you may want to consider Dirac delta function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function

Comment: the integral as written doesn't seem to converge for all $f\in L^2$, is there supposed to be a minus in the exponential?

Comment: @NinadMunshi, yes

Comment: @guest, No you have to assume I know nothing about distributions, even if I do a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the integrand has a Gaussian, consider the equivalent integral by the interchange $t' \leftrightarrow t-t'$:

$$\frac{1}{\epsilon} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t-t') e^{-\frac{t'^2}{4\epsilon^2}} dt'$$

then use the substitution $s' = \frac{t'}{2\epsilon}$:

$$ = 2\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\left(t - 2\epsilon s'\right) e^{-s'^2}ds'$$

and we can use dominated convergence to get

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} 2\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t-2\epsilon s') e^{-s'^2}ds' = 2f(t)\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-s'^2}ds' = \sqrt{4\pi}f(t)$$

I will leave the finding of the dominating function to you.

Comment: That's actually the sort of proof I was hoping for. I'm not really sure about the dominating function, I guess I only need to bound $f(t - 2\epsilon s')$, maybe I can use the $g(s) = ess \; sup f(t - 2\epsilon s)$?

Comment: @user8469759 kind of, you have to be wary of unruly counterexamples like $x^{-\frac{1}{4}}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{|x|<1}$, or worse, $x^{-1}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{|x|>1}$, or even these two stitched together (yikes). The beauty of the dominated convergence theorem is that only the integral of the function need have a bound, and you'll have to leverage the Schwartz decay of the Gaussian to your advantage.

Comment: Why does only the integral need to be bound? From the statement I can see that a sequence $f_n$ needs to be bound by an integrable function $g$.

Comment: @user8469759 right, I was being a little sloppy when I said that, but my point was that your immediate thought of a dominating function was a good one, but won't work if the function is unbounded, unless ess means something I'm unaware of. I meant that the dominating function is allowed to unbound, as long as its integral converges.

Comment: Hmmm that was my only guess unfortunately. Could you give me one more hint so I can give another go?

Comment: @user8469759 I would suggest having cases, where $|f|$ has a sup and one where it doesn't. In the case where it does not, stitch together a piecewise function such that it has one value within a neighborhood of size $1$ around its singularities (plural, potentially) and another value outside of it, like the Gaussian times a constant, that constant being the largest value of $|f|$ on that interval since by assumption we corralled off the only singularities earlier.

Comment: It doesn't seem easy to do, the essential supremum, the definition I know at least, is essentially the sup but you somehow discard values where the measure of the pre-image is 0. I'm not sure this covers all the cases, also how can I bound a function that doesn't have sup? maybe $f(t - 2\epsilon s)e^s$ has sup?

Comment: @user8469759 it...probably doesn't. It seems like, if I'm understanding it correctly, that the ess sup of the counterexample above is still infinite. But the recipe I gave should still work, and it doesn't seem too bad. One can usually assert such things exist, especially here since singularities in compact neighborhoods follow the other $p$ test where we need $p < 1$ for convergence. But since we have that the functions are $L^2$, we have $2p < 1$, which definitely does imply $ p < 1$.

Comment: @user8469759 to answer your other question, you bound a function without a sup by another function without a sup, that's what I was getting at in my previous comment. To give a concrete example, to use dominated convergence on $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{x}}dx$, one would use the dominating function $\frac{e}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $n\geq 1$, even though both functions did not have a sup on the domain of integration.

Comment: Hmmm, ok suppose I have just 1 singularity, at 0 to make my life simple. For any given such function in $L^2$ can I say that there's a neighboor of $0$ such that $|f| < \frac{1}{x^{p/2}}$ for some real $0 < p < 1$? Because if such bounding function wouldn't exist the function wouldn't be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, right? I can do a similar argument if the function isn't bounded at infinity. If it has other singularities I can shift my bounding function .

Comment: @user8469759 yes, and the constant in the numerator may not be one, it may need to be some arbitrary constant. One can prove what you wrote by contradiction, suppose there didn't exist $p$ such that that were true. That is equivalent to the hypothesis suppose $|f| > \frac{M}{x^{p/2}}$ for all $p < 1$ or $|f| > \frac{M}{x^{1/2}}$. Then $\int |f|$ diverges.

Comment: @user8469759 one final note, don't make the neighborhood around the singularities size $1$ because they can be arbitrarily close to each other. Give them some size $\delta$.

Comment: Sure, but as I said in my last comment *there's a neighboor*, it doesn't mean it's of size $1$.